# Java 17 Recursive @EntityListeners - Spring Data Jpa

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have two entities, Parent and Child.

The relationship is One parent can have many children and one child can have one parent.

Here are my classes:

```java
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "parent")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class Parent {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private UUID id;

    private String someThing;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "id.parent", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Child> children = new ArrayList<>();

    @Column(name = "createdAt")
    @CreatedDate
    private LocalDateTime createdAt;

    @Column(name = "updatedAt")
    @LastModifiedDate
    private LocalDateTime updatedAt;
    

}



@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "child")
@EntityListeners({AuditingEntityListener.class, ChildListener.class})
public class Child {

    @EmbeddedId
    @JsonIgnore
    private ChildPk id = new ChildPk();

    private String otherThing;

    @Column(name = "createdAt")
    @CreatedDate
    private LocalDateTime createdAt;

    @Column(name = "updatedAt")
    @LastModifiedDate
    private LocalDateTime updatedAt;
}
```

**What I need** is when a child got updated, the parent's "updatedAt" date got updated too.

For this, I have implemented the ChildListener that is an Entity Listener on the child class.

This is the code:

```java
public class ChildListener {

    private final ParentService parentService;

    public IntegracaoListener(@Lazy ParentService parentService) {
        this.parentService = parentService;
    }

    @PrePersist
    @PreUpdate
    private void before(Child child) {
        parentService.updateParentsUpdatedAt(child.getId().getParent().getId());
    }
}

// Parent Service:

@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public ParentService {
   private final ParentRepository repository;

    @Transactional
    public void updateParentsUpdatedAt(UUID id) {
        var parent = repository.findById(id).orElseThrow(() -> new SomeException(MessageError.SOMETHING));
            parent.setUpdatedAt(LocalDateTime.now());
            repository.saveAndFlush(parent); // This causes recursion.
            // repository.save(ambiente); This simply doesn't works.

    }
}
```

The problem here is: When `repository.saveAndFlush(parent);` is executed, it triggers again the method `ChildListener.before(...)` and again, and again... until JVM throws stackoverflow.

To solve this, I simply moved the  `ParentService.updateParentsUpdatedAt(...)` to another Thread, so the Listener will not notice any change on the entity:

```java
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public ParentService {
   private final ParentRepository repository;

    @Transactional
    public void updateParentsUpdatedAt(UUID id) {
        var thread = new Thread(() -> {
            var ambiente = repository.findById(id).orElseThrow(() -> new SomeException(MessageError.SOMETHING));
            ambiente.setDataModificacao(LocalDateTime.now());
            repository.saveAndFlush(ambiente);
            Thread.yield();
        });
        thread.setDaemon(true);
        thread.start();

    }
}
```

This works... but... is this the best solution for this problem?